# TCL ternary operator does not like empty string

Tags: tcl, ternary-operator

Simple question, TCL gives me "premature end of expression" because the last param of the ternary expression is an empty string. If it is anything else then it works ok. Can I use an empty string here?

```
set y 5
set x [expr ($y > 1) ? 1 : ""]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should always give `expr` a single, complete expression, wrapped in braces, as argument. This avoids a whole slew of problems, including this one.

```
expr {$y > 1 ? 1 : ""}
```

The problem is that `expr` concatenates its arguments to get an expression. The invocation `concat $y > 1 ? 1 : ""` gives the string "5 > 1 ? 1 : ", which can't be parsed by `expr`.

Comment: I'll never understand TCL fully but that is working :-)

Comment: @MikeKulls: never say never. Tcl is hard to get used to because it never tries to be clever, unlike some other languages. There are a small number of hard and fast rules, and they always apply. Once you learn to express yourself unequivocally, you'll get along fine with Tcl, and you'll find it easier to design programs in other languages as well.

Comment: I have to say I find it confusing. For example this code was failing for me today `if { $x eq Tx } { doSomething }`. Everywhere else strings don't require quoting and the docs even say not to use quotes.

Comment: @MikeKulls: the expr man page says "note that all literal operands that are not numeric or boolean must be quoted with either braces or with double quotes" (heading "operands"). This exception to the usual Tcl syntax is necessary because the final (after substitution) input string isn't Tcl source but a string in an infix-based expression language.